# Table caption inside tabular environment

Tags: tables, color, booktabs, ctable

I would like to write a table with latex which looks as similar as possible to this one here but I do not know how to add the caption to the header of the table as seen down below:

[image]

I reach as far as this here (see code down below) with only a "normal" standardized caption as we are used to from latex.

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05}

\usepackage[table,hideerrors]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,ctable}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{E7E8E8}
\rowcolors{1}{blue}{blue}
\begin{tabular}{ l c }
Parameter & Value \\ 
\specialrule{.1em}{.05em}{.05em}
\textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Value} \\
\midrule
Number of territories & 22 \\
Age of sexual maturity (years) & 2 \\
& \\
Winter mortality & \\
Mean of the winter strength distribution (days) & 117\\
\specialrule{.1em}{.05em}{.05em}
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Overview of processes, parameters and default values of the marmot model}
\label{tab:variables}
\end{center}
```

**Edit: Modified (near perfect!) table based on the responses to work with `multicol` package.**

```
\begin{center}
\refstepcounter{table} \label{tab:variables}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{E7E8E8}
\rowcolors{1}{blue}{blue}
\begin{tabular}{ L{5.1cm} C{2cm} }
\multicolumn{2}{L{\dimexpr7.1cm+2\tabcolsep\relax}}{%
\cellcolor{black}\color{white}\textbf{\small Table \ref{tab:variables} - Overview of processes, parameters, and default values of parameters of the Rapa Nui model}} \\
Parameter & Value \\ 
\specialrule{.1em}{.05em}{.05em}
\textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Value} \\
\specialrule{.1em}{.05em}{.05em}
Number of territories & 22 \\
Age of sexual maturity (years) & 2 \\
& \\
Winter mortality & \\
Mean of the winter strength distribution (days) & 117\\
\specialrule{.1em}{.05em}{.05em}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

So far, I have only two complains left:

- The caption has too much space above, unlike @Mico's example. I did not figure out how to change that!
- I did not managed to get the above code to function with `dcolumn` to align numbers suggested by @fldpi

**Edit2: my final version (updated Mico's final version of the table)**

```
\begin{center}
\refstepcounter{table} \label{tab:variables}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{E7E8E8}
\rowcolors{1}{blue}{blue}
\begin{tabular}{ L{5.1cm} d{3.0} }
\multicolumn{2}{L{\dimexpr7.1cm+2\tabcolsep\relax}}{%
\cellcolor{black}
\bfseries\small%
\textcolor{white}{Table \ref{tab:variables} -- Overview of processes, parameters, and default values of parameters of the marmot model}} \\
Parameter & 
\multicolumn{1}{C{2cm}}{Value} \\
\specialrule{.1em}{.05em}{.05em}
    Number of territories & 22 \\
    Age of sexual maturity (years) & 2 \\[1ex]
    Winter mortality & \\
    Mean of the winter strength distribution (days) & 117\\
\specialrule{.1em}{.05em}{.05em}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: I hope, you are not expecting us to type the whole stuff ;-) And you are missing `\usepackage{caption}`, most likely

Comment: A general introduction for how to create LaTeX tables can be found in the [LaTeX wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables). Furthermore, on this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear".

Comment: I understand your critical comments. I will do the job, no worries. I tend to open threads like this if I think that the outcome might be of interest for others, too. I was not sure if it is possible to create something like the mentioned table in latex at all, and hoped to get feedback for that. I will keep posting what I got.

Comment: I edit the question to be more specific. Check out the updated latex code as well. Thank you!

Comment: @TilHund - I've edited the title of your posting a bit more. For LaTeX users, "caption", "table", and "tabular" tended to be highly specific terms; it's important not to confuse people inadvertently, right?

Comment: Note the new edit in the original post above.

Comment: @TilHund - I've provided an addendum to address some of the new issues you've raise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer below focuses on getting the caption inside the `tabular` environment. It doesn't deal with colors or with inverted white on black printing as those would be to be secondary issues.

I suggest you do the following:

- Use a `table` environment.
- The first two instructions after `\begin{table}` should be `\refstepcounter{table}` and  `\label{tab:variables}`.
- Define the widths of the columns explicitly, say, `7.5cm` and `1cm`. To keep the code readable, I suggest you define new column types called, say, `L` and `C`, which each take a parameter (the usable width of the respective column). The `array` package provides the instruction `\newcolumntype` for just this purpose.
- Inside the `tabular`, use the instruction

  ```
  \multicolumn{2}{L{\dimexpr 8.5cm+2\tabcolsep\relax}}{%
    Table \ref{tab:variables} -- Overview of processes, parameters, and 
    default values of parameters of the marmot model}
  ```

  What's going on here? The material is being typeset across the two basic columns of the `tabular` environment. The combined with is `7.5cm + 1cm + 2\tabcolsep`. The admittedly somewhat inelegant-looking expression `\dimexpr 8.5cm+2\tabcolsep\relax` calculates this width "on the fly".
- The text of the caption starts with `Table \ref{tab:variables} --`: the argument of `\ref` should be the text string you used in the earlier `\label` instruction.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,array,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\refstepcounter{table} \label{tab:variables}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ L{7.5cm} C{1cm} }
\specialrule{.1em}{.05em}{.05em}
\multicolumn{2}{L{\dimexpr8.5cm+2\tabcolsep\relax}}{%
Table \ref{tab:variables} -- Overview of processes, parameters, and default values of parameters of the marmot model} \\
\specialrule{.1em}{.05em}{.05em}
\textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Value} \\
\midrule
Number of territories & 22 \\
Age of sexual maturity (years) & 2 \\
\addlinespace
Winter mortality & \\
Mean of the winter strength distribution (days) & 117\\
\specialrule{.1em}{.05em}{.05em}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to incorporate additional information provided by the OP:

- Use of `d` column type for second column; predetermined width of second column is maintained by using `\multicolumn{1}{C{1.3cm}}{\textbf{Value}}` instruction for header of second column
- Use of inverted colors in header

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo} \linespread{1.05}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{E7E8E8}
\rowcolors{1}{blue}{blue}

\usepackage{booktabs,array,ragged2e,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\refstepcounter{table} \label{tab:variables}
\begin{tabular}{ L{5.8cm} d{3.0} }
\multicolumn{2}{L{\dimexpr7.1cm+2\tabcolsep\relax}}{%
  \cellcolor{black}\color{white}\bfseries\small%
  Table \ref{tab:variables} -- Overview of processes, parameters, and default values of parameters of the Rapa Nui model} \\
\textbf{Parameter} & 
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.3cm}}{\textbf{Value}} \\
\specialrule{.1em}{.05em}{.05em}
Number of territories & 22 \\
Age of sexual maturity (years) & 2 \\[1ex]
Winter mortality & \\
Mean of the winter strength distribution (days) & 117\\
\specialrule{.1em}{.05em}{.05em}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am using the `multicol` package which does not(?) allow the table environment...

Comment: Awesome edit! You fast responses are very much appreciated. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to get the caption at the top would be to make it part of the table. You can use `\colorbox` to set the basic background colour and `\cellcolor` for the background of the caption and you can use the `dcolumn` package to align the decimal point of the values:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1} }

\begin{document}
\begingroup\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\colorbox{lightgray}{%
    \begin{tabular}{p{.2cm}ld{1}}
      \multicolumn{3}{p{\textwidth}}{\cellcolor{black}\color{white}\textbf{Table 1 - Overview of processes, parameters and default values of parameters of the marmot model}}\\
      \noalign{\smallskip}
      \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Parameter}} & \textbf{Value} \\
      \midrule
      & Number of territories & 22 \\
      & Age of sexual maturity (years) & 2 \\\\
      \multicolumn{2}{l}{Winter mortality} & \\
      & Mean of the winter strength distribution (days) & 117 \\
      & Standard deviation of the winter strength distribution (days) & 10.2 \\
      \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}%
}\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: How would you cross-reference such a table, using either the basic `\ref` method or something more complicated, like `\autoref` or `\cref`?

Comment: This solution functions with the `multicol` package but has issue with referencing as state by @Mico.

Comment: Note the new edit in the original post above.

Comment: Love the easier approach but, unfortunately, it does not function with `multicol` and does not(?) allow to reference on table. Thank you anyway for your reply. Much appreciated!